# javascript function that writes html that calls a javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So in the following code I let the javascript write the table's contense but for some reason as a result of the table body having been generated in this way the onchange function will not be called? Not sure why or of any solutions to get around this.

```
    var table = document.getElementById("tableOfTitles");
table.innerHTML = "<tr id='addrow'><td colspan='3'><input type='button' value='+' onclick='addRow()'/><select id='rowType' onchange='addRowDropDownChanged()'>";
```

All the code for the webpage - http://pastebin.com/ywvFywdz

Comment: Add your representative *minimal*/[SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) code into your *question* (hint: the [tag:php] is probably *not* relevant).

Comment: IDs must be unique? Can you reproduce the problem on http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Consider using JavaScript to hook up event handers at run-time, instead of defining them inline.

Comment: From the code directly in your question, i don't see a reason for it to not get called. I haven't dug through the pastebin yet.

Comment: the do simple tests, I usually use onclick='alert();' because alert() works every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using this instead of the inline javascript:

```
$("#tableOfTitles").on("change", "tr select", function(e) {
    addRowDropDownChanged();
    // Do other stuff here...
});
```

This will add an event handler to the `#tableOfTitles`, that is already be there when the javascript code is being executed (when the page gets loaded). The event will then be triggered every time a `tr select` element inside it gets changed.

Event handlers are registered only once. So if you add an event handler to an element, that doesn't exist yet (or add a handler afterwards), that one won't get triggered. You can avoid this, by simply adding this event to an already existing parent element (in your case the `#tableOfTitles`).